# How to display total of records in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I am trying to display total records in jqgrid.
Here is the code i am using to display.grid is displaying but i am not getting total.

and i am getting **Error:footer-row is invalid propert** 
Can anyone tell me what is mistake?

```
$("#JqGrid").jqxGrid(
              {
                  pagesize: 5,
                  source: dataAdapter,
                  width: 700,
                  sortable: true,
                  pageable: true,
                  autoheight: true,
                  columnsresize: true,
                  filterable: true,
                  showfilterrow: true,
                  showtoolbar: true,
                  footerrow: true,
                  userDataOnFooter:true,
                  rendertoolbar: function (toolbar) {
                      var container = $("<div style='overflow: hidden; position: relative; margin: 3px;'></div>");
                      var exportButton = $("<div style='float: right; margin-right: 5px;'>    <img style='position: relative; margin-top: 2px; width: 16px; height: 16px;' src='images/excel.png' /><span style='margin-left: 4px; position: relative; top: -3px;'>Export to Excel</span></div>");
                      container.append(exportButton);
                      toolbar.append(container);
                      exportButton.jqxButton({ width: 150, height: 20 });
                      exportButton.click(function (event) {
                          $("#JqGrid").jqxGrid('exportdata', 'xls', 'Report');
                      });
                  },
                  selectionmode: 'checkbox',
                  //rendertoolbar: function (toolbar) {
                  //    var container = $("<div style='overflow: hidden; position:relative;margin:3px;'></div>");

                  //    var exportButton = $("<div style='float:right;margin-right:20px;'><img style='position:relative;margin-top:2px;width:16px;height:16px' src='./images/excel.png'/><span style='margin-left:4px;position:relative;top:2px'>Export to Excel</span></div>");
                  //    exportButton.jqxButton({ width: '130' });
                  //    container.append(exportButton);
                  //    toolbar.append(container);
                  //}
                  columns: [
                             { text: 'VillageName', datafield: 'VillageName', width: 'auto' },
                             { text: 'Samples Collected', datafield: 'VillageSamples', width: 'auto' }

                  ],
                  gridComplete: function () {
                      calculateTotal();
                  },

              });
            var themeSetting = { theme: "darkblue" };
            $("#JqGrid").jqxGrid(themeSetting);
            var calculateTotal = function () {
                var gridData = $("#JqGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data'),
                    i = 0, totalAmount = 0, totalTax = 0;
                for (; i < gridData.length; i++) {
                    var rowData = gridData[i];
                    totalAmount += Number(rowData.VillageSamples);

                }
                $("#JqGrid").jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { name: 'TOTAL', VillageSamples: totalAmount });
            }
```

Comment: You created `jqxGrid` instead of `jqGrid`, but you tried to use `jqGrid` later. You should decide what product you use jqxGrid or jqGrid.

Comment: Jqxgrid I have to use

Comment: Then I can't help you. You should remove wrong call of `$("#JqGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data')`, `$("#JqGrid").jqGrid('footerData', 'set',....` and other calls of `jqGrid`. You should change the gag of your question from `jqgrid` and `jqgrid-asp.net` to `jqxgrid`. Only after that you will have chance that the people who works with `jqxgrid` will read your question.